# Magento2: Issue after installing module GA

Tags: magento2

I am installing GA module from:
https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html

But after installing this module, the store started walking **very very slowly**. I tries to run the deploy command and receives the issue:

[image]

Comment: Wetpixel google analytics extension have some errors. I have already tried that now I am using https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-analytics and it works fine.

Comment: If I uninstall this module, will this page start to walk normally?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Do you want ecommerce tracking or normal google analytics tracking?

Comment: I want ecommerce tracking thats why I have install this GA from welt :(

Comment: Then you can try this one as well: https://marketplace.magento.com/tatvic-enhancedecommerce.html

Comment: Dear, I have disable this module and then again try deploy but still I receive this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83158/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-sylvester).